# 401 unauthorized: Access token validation failure calling Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, bearer-token, azure-authentication

My goal is to get the list of sites with their web URL from REST API. I created one application in my tenant by granting it SharePoint API permissions.

I received the access token with client_credentials flow:

POST https://login.microsoft.com/864cc7c2-e44a-4a7e-bc1a-42b37ca38e66/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id - 3affdc0e-04b4-495f-9346-7f5beda9c5ce,

grant_type - client_credentials,

client_secret - xxxxxx,

scope - https://< mytenant >.sharepoint.com/.default

But the issue is when I use that token to call the API. When I pass the Bearer token to call API, it's giving 401 unauthorized error like this:

```
{ 'error': { 'code': 'InvalidAuthenticationToken', 'message': 'Access token validation failure. Invalid Audience. ' } }
```

I think I messed up somewhere but don't know where in particular. Can anyone help me out?

But if I call the same in Microsoft Graph, I'm getting what I want which is very strange.

Comment: I got role claims also in the decoded token. Any help?

Comment: Can you include the API call you are making and the permissions you granted?

Comment: I used this API call: `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?$select=siteCollection,webUrl`

Comment: Permissions I gave SharePoint `Sites.ReadWrite.All`

Comment: You have to change scope as `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` to get token as you are making Graph API call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got the below results:***

I created an Azure AD application and granted **SharePoint** permissions like this:

[image]

I generated the access token with same parameters as you like below:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I tried to get the list of sites with their web URLs using below query, I got the **same error**:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?$select=webUrl,siteCollection
```

**Response:**

[image]

***To resolve the error, you need to do changes like below:***

Make sure to grant API permissions for **Microsoft Graph** instead of SharePoint like below:

[image]

Change the scope as **`https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`** to get access token like below:

[image]

Using the above token, I got the list of sites with their **web URLs** successfully like below:

[image]

**Reference:**

[List sites - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-list?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: I resolved my issue following your steps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the token of the SPO api to call the graph API endpoint, you should call the SPO api endpoint to list the websites:

`GET https://{tenant-name}.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/sites`

Comment: When I tried this call, I got an error like `{ "error": {  "code": "accessDenied", "message": "There has been an error authenticating the request." } }` with status 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: Following @Sridevi M's answer, I resolved my issue by changing the scope to `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`.

Comment: Hi Carl. Please refrain from asking for votes here - content is upvoted/accepted organically. You can gently remind someone to accept if you think they might be new and don't know the conventions here, but go easy on it.